# Regular expression ensuring that string contains brackets

Tags: java, regex

I need help with regex, which ensures that my string `($921.00)` contains these brackets `(` `)`.
Values inside can be any length.

Comment: `s.indexOf('(') >= 0 && s.indexOf(')') >= 0`

Comment: How are you going to use this regex? Do you want to `find` this brackets? Does regex have to `match` entire string? Are brackets always at start and end of your string? Also, can we see what have you tried to solve this?

Comment: Tim B answered my question. Sorry, I am new in regex..

Comment: Are you sure you need regex for this? You can use `startsWith("(")` and `endsWith(")")`.

Comment: @sp00m that will match on the string ")(" so doesn't meet requirements. Pshemo's solution is good though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is to use the regex:

```
"\\(.*\\)"
```

If it must start and end with the brackets use:

```
"^\\(.*\\)$"
```

Comment: Second one worked like a charm!

Comment: Incidentally this is a handy site: http://regexpal.com/ I'm not sure if the syntax is completely identical to the Java flavour of regex but it's pretty close.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use regex. Follow this way of doing it:
    "\(.*\)"